# GSM SMS Gateway Buying Tips

Tags: sms, gsm, modem

I want to build a java application which will receive SMS & will reply automatically using text from database. I want to use GSM SMS Modem for this. I'll send/receive abt 200-250 SMS per hour. I have no idea about GSM SMS Modem. Can you give an idea which features I'll need to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.